# Ubuntu updating error. Something with internet?

Tags: upgrade, apt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using the Ubuntu archives?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234798/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-the-ubuntu-archives)

Everytime when I'm trying to update Ubuntu I always get these errors I hate so much.

```
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

And its says that there might be something wrong with the internet connection but my internet connection is perfect. Can anyone help me please? :)

Thanks, Sorry for bad english :)

Comment: Are you using a proxy in your System settings? (System settings>Netwrok>Proxy configuration)