# How can I fix a 404 Error using the Ubuntu archives?

Tags: upgrade, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

When running an update I get these errors:

> :Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
>   , 
>   W:Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic-backports/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
>   ,
>
> E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

There were more of the same kind of lines. How do I fix this?