# Error while upgrading to 12.04 --Trouble fetching files

Tags: 12.04, 11.04, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using the Ubuntu archives?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234798/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-the-ubuntu-archives)

While trying to upgrade, I got this error. Has anyone seen it before? Please advise me on what to do! Thank you!

```
W:Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found
W:Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
E:Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Don't worry yourself over fetching files from 11.04 if you're upgrading to 12.04. What the error is telling you is that it's unable to fetch files from 11.04 and old files are being used. Are you able to upgrade to 12.04?

Answer (score 1):

These are 'extras' for Ubuntu **11.04** ('Natty').

This release reached ***end-of-life*** recently, and is no longer supported for security and other updates.

See: [Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty Narwhal) reaches end-of-life on October 28, 2012](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2012/09/17/ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal-reaches-end-of-life-on-october-28-2012/)

If you need to be using a long-term-support release, you should be using **12.04 LTS** (or possibly **10.04 LTS** on very old equipment).

---

*If you are currently using **11.10** (Oneiric):*

Is there any reason you still have Natty-specific resources in your setup? Otherwise, removing these two lines will solve this error.

---

*If you are still on **11.04** (Natty):*

You should **not** be attempting to upgrade directly to **12.04**, but instead first upgrade to **11.10**.

**Note:** *As you have not already done so, and may not be up-to-date, it would be better to do a clean install of **12.04 LTS** instead (after backing-up all settings and user data). Any issues you may have with upgrading **from** 11.04 are **not** supported, as **11.04** is no longer supported.*