# Failed to fetch repositories

Tags: 10.10, apt, repository

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using the Ubuntu archives?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234798/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-the-ubuntu-archives)

I am having trouble downloading the Ubuntu repositories:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
...
Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz
404  Not Found 

Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages.gz
404  Not Found
...
```

I can connect to the server fine:

```
# ping archive.ubuntu.com
PING archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.92.202) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from sudice.canonical.com (91.189.92.202): icmp_req=1 ttl=52 time=149 ms
64 bytes from sudice.canonical.com (91.189.92.202): icmp_req=2 ttl=52 time=149 ms
64 bytes from sudice.canonical.com (91.189.92.202): icmp_req=3 ttl=52 time=149 ms

--- archive.ubuntu.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 149.221/149.305/149.355/0.321 ms
```

Here is my sources.list:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-updates main restricted universe 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted universe
```

and system details:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.10
Release:    10.10
Codename:   maverick
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As a release gets old (especially if it is not a LTS release), it becomes no longer hosted at archive.ubuntu.com. However, the repository [is still hosted](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/) at

```
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com
```

So try changing your repository source to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com.

Comment: Thanks - that did it. I am surprised there is no redirect.