# How to set up SMTP?

Tags: smtp

I want to send mail from a local server. I tried to install

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

but it showed this error

```
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/postfix/postfix
```

Please help me to enable SMTP in Ubuntu.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/234798/

Comment: It seems there is a problem with the Ubuntu archive. Sometimes indian servers seem to have problems. Does http://askubuntu.com/a/32097/236 help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/Release](http://askubuntu.com/questions/32064/failed-to-fetch-http-in-archive-ubuntu-com-ubuntu-dists-maverick-release)

Answer (score 0):

The archive is incorrect. I should read `http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/postfix`

To correct the problem: From terminal `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` this will open the text editor and you can correct the offending line.

Make the entry as above^^